SPGO - Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'firstChild')
I am having this issue, when logging in using my credentials.

But the Configure workspace worked totally fine:
{
    "sourceDirectory": "src",
    "sharePointSiteUrl": "https://xxxx.sharepoint.com/sites/TESTSITE",
    "workspaceRoot": "c:\\Users\\xxxx\\Documents\\xxxxxx\\TEST",
    "publishWorkspaceOptions": {
        "destinationFolder": "/",
        "globPattern": "c:\\Users\\xxxxxxxxx\\Documents\\xxxxxxxxx\\TEST\\src\\**\\*.*",
        "localRoot": "c:\\Users\\xxxxxxxx\\Documents\\xxxxx\\TEST\\src"
    },
    "publishingScope": "SaveOnly",
    "authenticationType": "Digest",
    "remoteFolders": [
        "/siteAssets/**/*"
    ]
}

I've been blocked for a couple of hours now, I will appreciate if anyone can answer. Thank you!
